# What is the difference between the geometric brownian motion and cumulative product of percentage returns?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, monte-carlo

I wonder why the following code: one using GBM and the other using cumulative product of normally distributed percentage returns slightly different values.

```
N = 1000000   # Number of random variables
r = 0
T = 10
sig = 0.15
S0 = 1

#Geometric Brownian Motion
X = (r-0.5*sig**2)*T + sig*ss.norm.rvs( 0 , np.sqrt(T), N)
S_T = S0 * np.exp(X)

#Cumulative product of normally distributed returns 
W = sig * ss.multivariate_normal.rvs( mean=0,  size=(T,N) )
S = np.cumprod(W+1,axis=0)[-1,:]

np.std(S_T) #0.50176
np.std(S) #0.49894
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could it be that you get different random numbers for each run?

Comment: In the above code, two different methods are being used: one uses the explicit solution, the other method is one that converges to GBM *for small enough values of* $\Delta T$